# NPE Defensive v try/catch?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am not advocating catching a `NullPointerException` as it is always a code smell/lazy approach.  But, consider you want to access a field deep inside  nested beans.

**Defensive NPE check**

```
if (  null != a && null != a.b() && null ! = a.b().c() && null !=   a.b().c().d() ) 
{
     doSomething( a.b().c().d().e );
}
```

**Lazy NPE Check**

```
try
{
     doSomething( a.b().c().d().e ); 
}
catch(NullPOinterException npe)
{
}
```

Two questions:

1. Performance

   At what depth [a,b,c....z as in the example above] is the heavier weight try/catch more efficient than Defensive NPE check?
2. Readability

   At what depth [a,b,c....z as in the example above] is the try/catch more readable than multiple &&?

Please don't answer 're-factor the nested beans' :-)

Comment: First code smell: `a.b().c().d().e`. Second code smell: why can things even be `null`? Finally: what do you do in the `else` / `catch` case?

Comment: *"Please don't answer re-factor the nested beans"* - that is **exactly** what you should do.

Comment: and why would you automatically assume the try/catch is more efficient?

Comment: Your actually question is irrelevant because the performance is completely irrelevant and both codes are not readable.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly valid question. Some beans can't be refactored because they come from a third party and you don't have the source code. Many SOAP and REST-based APIs return nulls instead of empty lists. It's unfortunately just the way it is. So @luk2302 the request not to re-factor the nested beans is not as silly as it sounds.

Comment: If you could use Groovy: `doSomething( a?.b()?.c()?.d()?.e );` (assuming `doSomething` can easily handle a null).

Comment: *Anything can be null* - that is a Java problem you can simply circumvent by not using null EVER and having every null lead to a crash immediately instead of dealing with it explicitly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if(null check)-else vs try catch(NullPointerException) which is more efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172367/ifnull-check-else-vs-try-catchnullpointerexception-which-is-more-efficient)

Comment: "Not using null EVER" -  that is neither practical or sensible in all but a 101 java program.   Any large enterprise system/ any touch points with 3rd party you must handle the null situations.  (Appreciate Optional<..> ).

Comment: @Stiltuske  I know( and stated in the question) the try/catch is less efficient i.e.  object creation v  checking if an area of memory is null. But I asked at what point they does multiple increasingly deep null checks become less efficient than a single try/catch ? :-)

Comment: I think the answer wrt performance depends a lot on expected percentage of finding a null and the processor architecture (predictive branching etc) and the answer wrt readability is opinion-based.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException i remember this one, it was actually a jcp proposal but not implemented i dont know why

Comment: Also there is Objects.requireNonNull and a bit more elegant solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/2386013/706695

Answer (score 1):

Try using Optional:

```
Optional.ofNullable(a)
    .map(A::b)
    .map(B::c)
    .map(C::d)
    .map(d -> d.e)
    .ifPresent(()->X::doSomething);
```

Not sure if it's any more readable. But sometimes it looks as if Optional is a class that is looking for ways to be used.